# How can I connect USB to TV (via AV port)

Tags: 10.04, video, tv

How to connect to TV with USB to AV cable?
I tried to connect, but nothing happened!
(10.04 Lucid)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be talking about a cable to be used with a digital camera, not a computer.

*does yours look like this?*

[image]

*or this*:

[image]

*This cable is meant to connect a digital camera to a TV. It's useless with computers*

There are adaptors, such as [the one in the first image](http://eu.startech.com/product/USB2VGA-USB-VGA-External-Multi-Monitor-Video-Adapter), that do this job. A few of them work well with Ubuntu, you should carefully select one that does if you're going to buy one, because may of them have problems.

But, I think you're probably not talking about this thing. So, no, a simple cable will not work.

Comment: you're wrong ! i'm talking about usb to av-out in TV

Comment: Please add a picture of what the cable looks like to your post. You will probably find one with google image search: it'd be very helpful.

Comment: sorry ! I can't found on google :(   ...the cable is to connect to the AV port in TV from usb port of the computer

Comment: Do you have a model number or a product name? Unfortunately, with the current information it could be a million different ones. Please also add the output of the command `dmesg` after you've plugged in the cable to your question, that'd be really helpful as well.